# My main maths stack exchange bookmarks r not showing

Tags: discussion, support, bookmarks

My all previous bookmarks are not there in the bookmarks section. Pls is it possible to bring it back the previous all bookmarks they were of very nice topics and detail explanation. Pls help moderators. (P.S. my reputation got reduced from 400+ to 101 for some reason)

Comment: Also i am new in this meta so dont know exact details i need to fill to meet the requirements of a gud question

Comment: Are you sure you log in using the same account?

Comment: Yes Sir about 50-60 bookmarks were there in main , i joined meta to ask for help . In this WayBig account only

Comment: But your account looks like a brand bew one. Indeed, you earned "supporter" only today, which means you casted your first upvote only yesterday

Comment: Actually no for some reason my reputation got lost from 400+ to 101

Comment: Thats why asked moderators to pls help

Comment: Looks like your MSE account had been deleted and you have a new one lately.

Comment: You just earned your 100 rep association bonus on 25th April. So this is a new acc. Period. You will need to ask why your old acc was deleted.

Comment: It seems your chemistry and physics accounts are older than this.  Maybe you are thinking of bookmarks there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, it seems very likely that you are talking about a deleted account. An account with userid 900638 called Waybig is still displayed [in Google Cache](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:https://math.stackexchange.com/users/900638/waybig?tab=profile), but [not on the site](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/900638/waybig).

Since the deletion seem to be rather recent, you could check your favorites using this [SEDE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/data-explorer/info) query: [Questions favorited by a specific user](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1401543/questions-favorited-by-a-given-user?userid=900638). (The questions won't be there after the next SEDE update, AFAICT the votes from deleted users are not stored in the SEDE database. So you'll see them there only this week. This is the status from the last update on this Sunday.)

At the moment, this query returns 44 result for the userid 900638.

Since SEDE still has your account in the users table, you can find also some other data about the old account. For example, a list of all [questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1401550/questions-answers-by-a-specific-user?userid=900638&type=1) and [answers](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1401550/questions-answers-by-a-specific-user?userid=900638&type=2). But both [questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/942474/questions-of-a-deleted-user?userid=900638) and [answers](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/942475/answers-of-a-deleted-user?userid=900638) can be obtained from SEDE for deleted accounts, too.

Comment: Very very thx yeah thats my deleted account and ik the reason why it was deleted , and ty for informing it will last just for a week " my favourites there" i can transfer into this new one

Comment: One more thing i want to ask in my new account i can now also see the previous questions notifications will it be deleted after a week u meant Sir ?

Comment: @WayBig I am not exactly sure how the notifications work if a user deleted an account and created a new one. (But since you say you can still see them, it seems plausible that the notifications might be tied to the [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/20960462/waybig).)

Comment: @MartinSleziak: thanks for this answer. I have cached the results from that SEDE query and I am now working on a method to get them to WizardMath if they haven't gotten them for themself.